# failed with the error: The Web server cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to host CMMS project in iis and while I was playing around something went wrong and I could not figure out what happened, finally I have tried to open my project as usual using visual studio 2013 but it failed to load and it shows this message "Creation of the virtual directory with error: the web server could not be found "

Refer to this image :

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1909851.aspx?Unable+to+open+the+web+site+The+web+server+could+not+be+found+